# Installing JCC Ubuntu asking for path varaiable

Tags: java, python

I am trying to install JCC.

Steps:

- `svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/pylucene/trunk/jcc`
- `sudo python setup.build`

I am getting this error:

> Java JDK directory '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64' does not exist.  Please set the environment variable JCC_JDK to the correct location before help.

Comment: Here is a link on how to set environment variables in Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

```
export JCC_JDK='path/to/javahome'; pip install jcc
```

or if you want to install from source:

```
export JCC_JDK='path/to/javahome'; python setup.py install;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to install setuptools from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files

Then, go the jcc folder we downloaded. The default folder is: ~/jcc

Then, using this command: sudo python setup.py install

By the way, the second line of the commands you have is not correct. 'sudo python setup.build' should be 'sudo python setup.py install'

check the site: http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/install.html

And the system I use is Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit